# Why is the print function not working in open_with?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am starting a module that opens a file, reads it, does some stuff, and then appends to it. However, I am trying to see what is in the file first. Here is the start of the program:

```
def addSkill(company):
    with open("companies.txt", "a+") as companies:
        for line in companies:
            print('ok')
            print(line.rstrip('\n'))
        companies.write(company + '\r\n')

    companies.close()
```

Neither of the print functions are working. There is text in the document. And it appends to it as requested. Any suggestions?

Comment: You use `a`, so the cursor is located at the end of the file.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem you should list that as an answer so you get credit.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong but I thought I read that for a+ and reading the cursor was placed at the beginning? Is there an efficient way to read and append without doing seperate w and a methods

Comment: [`companies.seek(0)`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek) should set you back to the start.

Answer (score 2):

Just open using `'r+'` then save in memories everything that you need, then it will automatically writing at the end. because your file descriptor will be at the end.

Opening files in `'a'` automatically put your file descriptor at the end, therefore, your can't see what was written before that.

e.g

```
def addSkill(company):
    with open('companies.txt', 'r+') as fd:
        list_of_companies = fd.readlines()
        fd.write(company + '\n')

list_of_companies.append(company) # adding the last company to the full list.
print('\n'.join(list_of_companies)) # print each company with a '\n'.
```

**Bonus**: your `close()` method is useless using `with`, python will do that for you.

In any cases, when you are unsure about the option of a function, please [**RTFM**: `open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

- `'r'`    open for reading (default)
- `'w'`    open for writing, truncating the file first
- `'x'`    open for exclusive creation, failing if the file already exists
- `'a'`    open for writing, appending to the end of the file if it exists
- `'b'`    binary mode
- `'t'`    text mode (default)
- `'+'`    open a disk file for updating (reading and writing)
- `'U'`    universal newlines mode (deprecated)